# Android phone how to restore contacts

Tags: android

I routinely backup (copy) all my Android phone's files to a portable hard drive using my PC.

My old phone died. They sent me a new one. I restored all my old files to the new phone, but my old contacts did not restore.

What have I done wrong? Is there some trick to restoring files?

Comment: Contacts app require `.vcf` file, and contacts, SMS, MMS records are not synced between google accounts.  If you used Hangouts at some point, try installing it on a new phone. Maybe it recorded something.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my question. I copied (restored) ALL files from the backup of my old Android phone to the new phone. Therefore, the .vcf file, etc. was copied back. This is a routine chore using Windows, but maybe there's something in Android that's mucking the copy operation up?

Comment: How did you back up your phone data, and copied how? Contacts app generates vCard file when you export contacts. If you have that file, you can import it from your google drive, or SD card using import/export option under it's menu.

Comment: If you just copied and pasted all the files from internal storage, it won't do it. The versions of both androids and contacts app are probably different, and contacts are stored in sqlite database.

Comment: I am a Windows guy. Not an Android guy so I think in terms of Windows. You seem to be an Android guy who knows little about Windows. My many years of experience and my degrees in Computer Science tell me that using Windows to copy all files (backup) to a portable hard drive then doing the reverse to my my new phone should have fixed the problem UNLESS there's some kind of hidden protection within Android that gets in the way. I plugged my phone into the USB socket on my Windows computer to do the backup & restore.

Comment: Pro tip: Sync your contacts to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `Contacts1.1` as a Windows program that reads it's data from a location that user cannot change... Say, `C:\Users\sam\contacts\`... You backup your `C:\Users\sam\` directory, and restore it on another Windows machine that has Contacts2.0 installed. Now, your contacts are in the new system as binary data, but if `Contacts2.0` is reading them from `C:\Program Files\Contats` only, you wont be able to see them.

You could manually move them, but what if they are also in different format?
In a real scenario, database fields might be different.

That's why you manually export/import data to/from a format that is supported on every version of that program. Program then stores the data as it likes.
Windows Mail client for example uses `.eml`, Outlook uses `.pst`, and Contacts uses `.vcf`.

Comment: Try finding  `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db`. If it was backed up, you may still be able to restore the contacts.

Comment: There is no contacts.db in my backup. I guess I'll just have to give up on finding a solution in this forum.